# <object> onload not firing in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events

Loading a PDF in an `<object>` tag, I want to show an indicator while the document is being loaded instead of just an empty element, so I positioned a Load Panel over the `<object>`. I added a function to hide the panel:

```
function documentLoaded() {
    // Code to hide panel here.
}
```

And set it to fire in the `onload` event of the `<object>` tag:

```
<object type="application/pdf" data="/documents/sample.pdf" onload="documentLoaded();"></object>
```

This is working exactly how I want it to in Firefox and in Edge, but when I tested it in Chrome the Load Panel never went away. When I debugged it I saw that the `documentLoaded()` function was never called at any point.

Is there another way to get this to work with Chrome, or another way completely to call a JS function once the PDF is ready?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector('#load_panel').onload=documentLoaded()
```

Comment: Hi Leonid, Can you elaborate on your answer? Right now, your answer is just a line of code with no explanation.